# Hi, I am looking books to learn math from scratch

Tags: self-learning

I have seen posts on this site someone refered to khan academy, but I don't want to watch videos, so I have got to learn math from books. I want to learn it very very beginning.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it really depends what you mean from the ‘very
very beginning’. A book series that you could buy is the Art of Problem Solving books (https://artofproblemsolving.com/store) which have a book series from pre-algebra to calculus. However, this can get very expensive.

Edit: As mentioned below, The Art of Problem Solving Books sort of do what they say on the tin, and develop a sense of problem solving. If that is something you want to develop then these books are recommended, however, if you just want to learn the basics, then other books may be more suitable (for example Open Stax has a series of books in a similar style to a traditional course).

Comment: Yes, that's it what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that the Art of Problem Solving books contain very challenging olympiad-style problems. If you read those books, you have to be able to not get discouraged if you struggle a lot with the problems. The exercises you find in a typical math book are way easier.

Comment: @littleO Good point, I have hopefully added clarity in my edit

Comment: I would never choose a book of problems to learn Mathematics. A great book by three first class soviet mathematicians  is https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi8y-G8_I_qAhWkKH0KHfLADhYQFjACegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F405880.Mathematics&usg=AOvVaw22Ni0har6K7R0n0zEBF7KG

Comment: @GReyes They're not just books of problems, they are real textbooks that explain the material well. They just also contain hard problems, along with training about how to solve hard problems.

Comment: That book explains the philosophy of Math and many fundamental ideas

Comment: I have heard that's a great book, yes.

Comment: @Greyes The book you suggest looks very appealing, however, I am uncertain about how basic it is, especially as the synopsis claims to explain topics such as partial differential equations.

Comment: @littleO I may be misjudging the book you mention.. also, I am probably a bit biased because I have seen many students at good universities trying, unsuccessfully, to "learn by doing". My advice to them is to stop solving problems, step back and just think about the bigger picture. And that is what books like the one I mentioned help with.

Comment: V.I. Arnold mentioned in some of his writings that half of the Math he knew he learned from the book on the development of Mathematics in the XIX century by F. Klein. Another great book from which you learn something new whenever you browse it.